# angular-filter ng-repeat filterBy not equal to

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am repeating over a list of parameters using ng-repeat. One of the properties on a parameter is accessibility.
Accessibility can be one of 3 values. Public, ReadOnly or Private.

I would like my repeat to only repeat when the accessibility is Public or ReadOnly.

using

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.parameters | filterBy: ['accessibility'] : 'Public' | groupBy: 'groupName'">
```

I get all the public parameters but I cannot get it to use a negated filterBy

Comment: This works but is not the most elegant solution   

<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.parameters | xor: [{accessibility:'Private'}]: 'accessibility' | groupBy: 'groupName'">

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could do something like this, where `accessibility` is filter and on the filter you could check on what its `type` and push the `values`.

```
<div class="form-group" 
        ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.parameters | accessibility | groupBy: 'groupName'">

youApp.filter('accessibility', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return output;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
That would require adding JS to my app. I was hoping to do it purly with the Angular-filter plugin.
Can I not add multiple options. So instead of saying not private I say public or readonly

Comment: @russelrillema: that would the better way as you hold the control, even if tomorrow a new type is been added... which requires some condition to be met.